# $\pi_1$-equivalence of CW-complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups, cw-complexes

**Definition**. We call $\pi_1$-equivalence the closure of a binary relation between topological spaces "there is a continuous mapping inducing an isomorphism of fundamental groups" to an equivalence relation.

**Questions**:

1. Are there two non-$\pi_1$-equivalent CW-complexes with isomorphic fundamental groups?
   ([here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/408138/148161) Achim Krause gave an example of two CW-complexes with isomorphic fundamental groups between which there is no continuous mapping inducing isomorphism, but are there any invariants that could impede the chain of such mappings?).
2. If so, what are the $\pi_1$-equivalence invariants of CW-complexes?

It is clear that a CW-complex is $\pi_1$-equivalent to its
2-skeleton, so we can restrict ourselves to two-dimensional
CW-complexes.

Comment: @DanielH.Hartman No, I have not heard of such a concept anywhere, I would also be interested in the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any pair of 2-dimensional (connected) CW-complexes $X$ and $Y$, if $\pi_1(X)$ is isomorphic to $\pi_1(Y)$ then there exist maps going each way $X \mapsto Y$ and $Y \mapsto X$ that induce isomorphisms on $\pi_1$. Using what you have already written that the 2-skeleton is $\pi_1$-equivalent to the whole complex, it follows that the only invariant of $\pi_1$-equivalence is the fundamental group itself.

For the proof, first pick $0$-cells $p \in X$ and $q \in Y$ and an isomorphism $\phi : \pi_1(X,p) \to \pi_1(Y,q)$. Now define $f : X \to Y$ as follows. Pick a maximal subtree $T$ in the $1$-skeleton $X^{(1)}$, hence $T$ contains each $0$-cell. Define the restriction $f \mid T$ to be the constant with value $q$.

Next, orient and enumerate the edges $\{e_i\}_{i \in I}$ of $X^{(1)}-T$. Associated to each $e_i$ is an element $[\gamma_i] \in \pi_1(X,p)$ where $\gamma_i = \alpha_i e_i \beta_i$, $\alpha_i$ is the path in $T$ from $p$ to the initial $0$-cell of $e_i$, $\beta_i$ is the path in $T$ from the terminal $0$-cell of $e_i$ to $p$. So far the map is already defined on $\alpha_i$ and on $\beta_i$ to map those paths to the single point $q$, because $f$ is already defined on $T$ so as to take all of $T$ to $q$. Therefore $f$ is already defined on the edge $e_i$ so as to map the endpoints of $e_i$ to the single point $q$. Now extend $f$ over the rest of the edge $e_i$, defining $f \mid e_i$ to be any closed path in $Y$ based at $p$ which represents $\phi[\gamma_i]$.

It follows that, so far, $f$ has been defined on the closed path $\gamma_i = \alpha_i * e_i * \beta_i$ based at $p$ so as to take $[\gamma_i]$ to a closed path $f(\gamma_i)$, based at $q$, representing $\phi[\gamma_i]$.

Finally, for any $2$-cell $d$, its attaching map $\chi_d : S^1 \to X^1$ is homotopic to some path of the form $\gamma_{i_1} \cdots \gamma_{i_K}$, and then since $[\gamma_{i_1} \cdots \gamma_{i_K}]\in \pi_1(X,p)$ is the identity it follows that $\phi[\gamma_{i_1} \cdots \gamma_{i_K}] \in \pi_1(Y,q)$ is the identity and so $f(\gamma_{i_1} \cdots \gamma_{i_K})$ is homotopic to a constant in $Y$. From this it follows that $f \circ \chi_d$ is homotopic to a constant in $Y$. Using this homotopy we can therefore extend $f$ continuously over $d$.

Comment: You definitely cannot send loops to any loop from the respective class. Imagine that you have two loops having a common initial segment, and then diverge along different edges from the complement of the spanning tree. Then their images must also have a common initial segment. But, for example, for a circle (as well as for any non-single-point connected CW-complex) in any homotopy class there are two loops that do not have an initial common segment.

Comment: Yes, if we can determine f on a 1-dimensional skeleton correctly, then further definition on disks works great, thanks!

Comment: We can first fold the spanning tree in the first CW complex and then easily direct the loops of the first to the loops of the second. This does not prove the statement you are claiming, but it is enough for π_1-equivalence, thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps you should somehow correct the mistake in your answer before I accept it?

Comment: As said in my answer, the first step is to define $f$ on the spanning tree $T$ so as to take $T$ to the single point $q$. The second step is to define $f$ on each edge $e_i \subset X^{(1)}-T$ so as to take $e_i$ to a loop in $Y$ based at $q$, chosen so as to represent $\phi[\gamma_i]$. Which of those steps are you asking about?

Comment: I did add a few more details to the explanation of how $f \mid e_i$ is defined.

Comment: Ah, and I fixed what might have been a bad typographical error, $f \bar T$ instead of $f \mid T$.

Comment: Oh, indeed, you originally wrote everything correctly, sorry.